# XML parsing in R

Tags: xml, r

How do I extract the address from XML that looks like this:

```
<address class=\"addressReset\"> 
    <span rel=\"v:address\"> 
        <span dir=\"ltr\">
            <span class=\"street-address\" property=\"v:street-address\">77 Yesler Way</span>, 
            <span class=\"locality\">
                <span property=\"v:locality\">Seattle</span>, 
                <span property=\"v:region\">WA</span> 
                <span property=\"v:postal-code\">98104-2530</span>
             </span> 
        </span> 
     </span> 
</address>
```

I want to extract the values into variables `streetAddr`, `City`, `State`, `Zipcode`.

I tried doing:

```
require(XML)
data <- xmlParse(Address)
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
```

but my `xml_data` is very unformatted and I do not know how to work with it. For example,

```
xml_data$body$address$span$span$span$text
```

gives the street address. Is there a better way for me to parse this? Can I use the class and property to get the values I want?

Comment: posting valid & formatted (lines & indents) XML would go a long way to help ppl who you are asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `library(XML)` solution uses [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev). Parse the text

```
library(XML)
xml = xmlParse(txt)
```

Create the XPath queries

```
properties = c("street-address", "locality", "region", "postal-code")
queries = sprintf("//span[@property='v:%s']/text()", properties)
names(queries) = properties
```

Retrieve the results using `xpathSApply()` and `xmlValue()` on each query

```
sapply(queries, xpathSApply, doc=xml, fun=xmlValue)
```

The result is a (character) matrix

```
> sapply(queries, xpathSApply, doc=xml, fun=xmlValue)
      street-address  locality      region  postal-code 
[1,] "77 Yesler Way" "Seattle"     "WA"    "98104-2530"
[2,] "88 Yesler Way" "Seattttttle" "WAAAA" "99999-2530"
```

Answer (score 1):

why not make an XML tree and navigate?

```
library(XML)
datatree <- xmlTreeParse(Address)
topNode <- xmlRoot(datatree)
address <- xmlSApply(topNode, function(x) xmlSApply(x[[1]][[1]][[1]], xmlValue))
print(address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `xml2`:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

txt <- '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<addresses>
<address class=\"addressReset\"> 
<span rel=\"v:address\"> 
<span dir=\"ltr\">
<span class=\"street-address\" property=\"v:street-address\">77 Yesler Way</span>, 
<span class=\"locality\">
<span property=\"v:locality\">Seattle</span>, 
<span property=\"v:region\">WA</span> 
<span property=\"v:postal-code\">98104-2530</span>
</span> 
</span> 
</span> 
</address>
<address class=\"addressReset\"> 
<span rel=\"v:address\"> 
<span dir=\"ltr\">
<span class=\"street-address\" property=\"v:street-address\">88 Yesler Way</span>, 
<span class=\"locality\">
<span property=\"v:locality\">Seattttttle</span>, 
<span property=\"v:region\">WAAAA</span> 
<span property=\"v:postal-code\">99999-2530</span>
</span> 
</span> 
</span> 
</address>
</addresses>
'

doc <- read_xml(txt)

properties <- c("v:street-address", "v:locality", "v:region", "v:postal-code")

map_df(xml_find_all(doc, "//address"), function(x) {

  data.frame(as.list(set_names(map_chr(properties, function(y) {
    xml_text(xml_find_all(x, sprintf(".//span[@property='%s']", y)))
  }), properties)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

})

## Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
## 
##   v.street.address  v.locality v.region v.postal.code
##              (chr)       (chr)    (chr)         (chr)
## 1    77 Yesler Way     Seattle       WA    98104-2530
## 2    88 Yesler Way Seattttttle    WAAAA    99999-2530
```

I'm assuming there's a parent tag. That may be a bad assumption, but it should be straightforward to extrapolate.

For each address, extract each span with the named property, turn them into data frames and bind them all together.